# Load Vue.js component via ajax from server

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I need some help with vue.js and loading vue.js component via ajax from server.

I create a photo gallery. With async photo loading.

Index.php:

```
<div id="app"><photo></photo></div>
```

Backend(php):

```
echo json_encode(array('photo' => '<photo><img src=“...”></photo>'));
```

Frontend works fine, but if I click on "next" button and place loaded component to DOM(in my #app: $(‘#app’).html(response.photo) ), vue.js is not reprocessed loaded HTML.

The problem is that the loaded HTML (with AJAX) is not reprocessed (recompiled) by Vue.

How to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can try [this](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader)

Comment: Sorry. This will not work. I expecting something like this(in callback in my “next” button): $.ajax({..., success: function(data) {  $(‘#app’).html(data.photo);  app.__vue__.reinitialise(); } })

Comment: Your server should ONLY return the contents of the image. Not the entire vue component. That's how things are done correctly. If you don't put yourself into position where problem occurs, no problem will occur.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! I understand, that I need to change the implementation.But I can't to realize all Vue.js ideas and techniques. In this moment, I can to use only the SPA components in my non-SPA site.